# How to Obfuscate GCM key for Android Push Notification

Tags: android, push-notification, obfuscation, google-cloud-messaging

The server key stays in the code, so if someone decompiles the source eventually they can see the key even with proguard on i believe.  How can i get proguard to obfuscate this or at least optimize the obfuscation.

Comment: "The server key stays in the code" -- that code is on your server. That is why they call it the "server key". "so if someone decompiles the source eventually they can see the key even with proguard on i believe" -- how will they get the source to your server app?

Comment: Hi, im referring to the google project Id:

Comment: public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService  {    public GCMIntentService() {
        super("my_project_ID_goes here");
            }   ...... ..... ....

Comment: What specific problem are you expecting to occur if somebody sees your project ID?

Comment: Someone can push notifications to all subscribers. and can pretend to me someone there not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no problem here. There are two "keys", the senderId (which belongs in the Android Code) and your API Key.
The senderId in the App only states from which server the APP will allow receiving messages. There is no way someone can exploit this to send messages.
The API Key should be kept secret. This is the key used in the server to identify at the GCM Server. This key should NOT in any case be in the source of your app.
So i suggest you carefully re-read the GCM Guide in order to understand the complete relations.

Comment: Your right, i was having a brain fart.  I got the GOOGLE_API_KEY mixed up with the Sender key ....the GOOGLE_API_KEY i've kept securely on my server.  this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i get proguard to obfuscate this

You can't. DexGuard, the commercial offshoot of ProGuard, has some ability to obfuscate data, but it is unlikely to be especially useful, as would any home-grown solution of your own. All an attacker needs to do is get your APK, replace the superclass of your GCMIntentService with their own, and record the value.

> Someone can push notifications to all subscribers

If you have evidence that this is possible, please contact security@android.com. Since the project ID is not involved in sending notifications, I fail to see how your attack will work, but perhaps I am missing something.